# why MVC complains about passing a DBQuery when i pass an object to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

hi i have the following Edit action to the Edit view

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var deparments = db.Departments.Select(e => new DepartmentModel { DeparmentId = e.DepartmentId, Name = e.Name }).ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in deparments)
    {
        ddl.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.DeparmentId.ToString() });
    }

    var employee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
                    .Select(e => new NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
                    {
                        EmpID = e.EmpId,
                        FirstName = e.FirstName,
                        LastName = e.LastName,
                        DeptColl = ddl,
                        DeptId = e.DepartmentId.ToString() //this set the selected value
                    });

    return View(employee);
}
```

its **Edit view:**

```
@model VirtualCampus2.Models.NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeptId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeptId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeptId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

it complains with [this error show on video](https://youtu.be/VUssLtv11gI)

error in text is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VirtualCampus2.Models.NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'VirtualCampus2.Models.NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel'.

updates:

```
public class NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    public List<SelectListItem> DeptColl { get; set; }
    public string DeptId { get; set; }
}
```

what it throws this error and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Index code I made some false data (Test purposes only)

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> ddlColl = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="By Emp No", Value="1", Selected=true },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="By Name", Value="2" }
            };

            List<EmployeeModel> list = new List<EmployeeModel>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var employee =
                new EmployeeModel
                {
                    EmpID = 1,
                    FirstName = "Name" + i.ToString(),
                    LastName = "LastName" + i.ToString(),
                    DeptId = i * 10,
                    DepartmentName = "DepName" + i.ToString()
                };
                list.Add(employee);
            }



            IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> employees = list;


            EmployeeViewModel evm = new EmployeeViewModel { DDLCollecton = ddlColl, Employees = employees };

            return View(evm);
        }
```

In your Edit code I made some false data (Test purposes only)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            List<DepartmentModel> list = new List<DepartmentModel>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var department =
                new DepartmentModel
                {
                    DeparmentId = i * 10,
                    Name = "DepName" + i.ToString()
                };
                list.Add(department);
            }

            IEnumerable<DepartmentModel> deparments = list;

            List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in deparments)
            {
                ddl.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.DeparmentId.ToString() });
            }

            List<EmployeeModel> listr = new List<EmployeeModel>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var employeer =
                new EmployeeModel
                {
                    EmpID = 1,
                    FirstName = "Name" + i.ToString(),
                    LastName = "LastName" + i.ToString(),
                    DeptId = i * 10,
                    DepartmentName = "DepName" + i.ToString()
                };
                listr.Add(employeer);
            }



            IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> employees = listr;

            var Selectedemployee = employees.Where(e => e.EmpID == id)
                            .Select(e => new NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
                            {
                                EmpID = e.EmpID,
                                FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                LastName = e.LastName,
                                DeptColl = ddl,
                                DeptId = e.DeptId.ToString() //this set the selected value                          
                            }).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(Selectedemployee);
        }
```

It works perfectly so your issue is with getting the DB data not the controller code itself.

Make sure that employee in the Edit controller is either a:

`IEnumerable<EmployeeModel>`
or 
`List<EmployeeModel>`

Maybe something like would be good for debugging the issue:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var deparments = db.Departments.Select(e => new DepartmentModel { DeparmentId = e.DepartmentId, Name = e.Name }).ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in deparments)
    {
        ddl.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.DeparmentId.ToString() });
    }

    var employeeList = db.Employees().ToList();

    var employee = employeeList.Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
                    .Select(e => new NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
                    {
                        EmpID = e.EmpId,
                        FirstName = e.FirstName,
                        LastName = e.LastName,
                        DeptColl = ddl,
                        DeptId = e.DepartmentId.ToString() //this set the selected value
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(employee);
}
```

Comment: thanks for efforts, when i run the code Edit() action fills data in "departments" then the foreach fills "ddl" and in the last LINQ query "ddl " shows it has data here is video i have uploaded to youtube that shows data on those object https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44B06FIGvrw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you are a life saver! like mentioned in your code when i write  var employeeList = db.Employees().ToList(); then do LINQ on it it worked : )  but why it didnt work before what difference does ToList() make in this scenario??

Comment: Glad I could help, ToList() changes it from an expression to a List so you are only passing the results, for me it is one of the only downsides to LINQ but on the other hand can be very useful :) good luck with your project @PhillGreggan

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the query where you state at the top of the view that you need the model to be returned, if you only want to return one item in the model then why don't you use the following:

```
var employee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
                    .Select(e => new NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
                    {
                        EmpID = e.EmpId,
                        FirstName = e.FirstName,
                        LastName = e.LastName,
                        DeptColl = ddl,
                        DeptId = e.DepartmentId.ToString() //this set the selected value
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

As for other problem:

```
 List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in deparments)
    {
        ddl.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Name, Value = item.DeparmentId.ToString() });
    }
```

You didn't have parentheses after new SelectListItem

These two bits of code should solve your problem

Comment: i need the projection as i stated on the original query because certain form data depends on it

Comment: Try new version @PhillGreggan

Comment: is the latest version same the version chris recommend if so gives the same errror "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: Slightly different, uses First or Default instead, maybe will make a difference. @PhillGreggan

Comment: You don't need parenthesis when you're doing object initialization unless you also need to pass something to the constructor, which is not the case here. `new SelectListItem { .. }` is perfectly valid. In fact, it's a bit of an anti-pattern to actually include the parenthesis in this case.

Comment: I have tested the above code based on what i know from your project and it works perfectly well @PhillGreggan

Comment: @hjardine still no luck with mine though, i even removed that "ddl" from the last LINQ projection still it gives teh same error but there is another List<SelectItemList> in NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel. i have updated my orignal code with that class

Comment: If you post the ViewModel code then it will probably be easier to find the problem @PhillGreggan

Comment: @hjardine i have posted it

Comment: There is only one List<SelectListItem> in posted viewmodel?

Comment: @hjardine in NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel yes only one its for the dropdown box with departments

Comment: @hjardine other thing is i havent't written code for the dropdown box bind in the Edit's view but i dont think it has any connection with the error as this is a incorrect pass (prior) now the selectItemList

Comment: @hjardine would you like to have a look at my code, i can post it on google drive?

Comment: Yes i will have a look, as long as there is no sensitive data

Comment: @hjardine give me a couple of mins! TY

Comment: @hjardine here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2bAxlTCSUc3ekdGU0pKSjhpZ0E/view?usp=sharing  this is micro level application to test some basic asp mvc crud operations

Comment: @PhillGreggan ill have a look

Comment: Your projects works on mine, but i made my own data, so there must be a problem with either what or how you are retrieving from the DB (I don't have access to your DB)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight-forward. The model for the view is declared as:

```
@model VirtualCampus2.Models.NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
```

But you're passing it a collection of `NewEmployeeDepartmentDDLViewModel`s. The fact that there's probably only one instance in that collection is beside the point. This is because you're using `Where`, most likely so you can call `Select` off of it. That's fine but you still need `SingleOrDefault`, to pull the instance out of the collection.

```
var employee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
                .Select(e => new NewEmployeeDeparmentDDLViewModel
                {
                    EmpID = e.EmpId,
                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
                    LastName = e.LastName,
                    DeptColl = ddl,
                    DeptId = e.DepartmentId.ToString() //this set the selected value
                }).SingleOrDefault();
```

However, you should also be ensuring that you actually get something back from your query. `SingleOrDefault` will either return the instance or `null`. So you should have a condition like:

```
if (employee == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Before returning the view.

**UPDATE**

> when i did that it complained about "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

That one is actually caused by passing something to a LINQ query that can't be evaluated into a static value at query time. There's nothing like that happening here in this particular bit of code, so there's somewhere else you're making a LINQ query where this is happening. One quick example I run into constantly because I always forget on first run is with Identity's `GetUserId()`. Say I want to get a particular object belonging to a user:

```
var foo = db.Foos.Where(m => m.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

That will fail with the same exception. To get around it, you need to do something like:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var foo = db.Foos.Where(m => m.UserId == userId);
```

Now, the LINQ query is working with a primitive type that it can easily convert into a SQL query, whereas, before, it had no idea how to write a query that included `User.Identity.GetUserId()`. Other common causes are using things like `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (only `IsNullOrEmpty` is supported) or `ToLowerInvariant` (only `ToLower` is supported).

Basically whenever a LINQ query has to be converted to a SQL query because you're hitting a database, there's only a subset of framework methods you're allowed to utilize. This is because these have to be converted into an appropriate SQL equivalent, which not every method can be, especially custom methods you write on classes.

Comment: when i did that it complained about "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: why are you talking about GetUserID? he is passing the int to the controller already and it is an edit form so not necessarily editing the particular user? @ChrisPratt

Comment: @ChrisPratt still no luck worst, still cannot figure out i have updated my post with the ViewModel